# Stencil scale along x - Texture Paint mode

Tags: texture-painting

I am trying this cool feature - stencil texture painting. I am able to scale stencil using shift+RMB, but that scales the stencil in both x and y.

Is there a way to scale it only along x or only y ?

Comment: Where do you find this feature?

Comment: you can find it in texture painting mode. while painting a texture on an object you can go from tiled to stencil. And there it is, now you can paint texture as stencil.

Comment: it kind of works if you hold shift+X+RMB or shift+Y+RMB and then shift+RMB

Comment: Thanks Faceb. i also tried things , but didn't think of that. thanks a lot.

Comment: it flashes, and depends when you release the RMB while it flashes

Comment: yeah this is currently really flaky even in 2.78, it seems you have to just tap X or Y whilst holding shift, don't hold down the X or Y as it flashes like crazy, odd there's no values being shown in the UI when you scale the texture.

Answer (score 4):

You have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Right mouse button, then while still holding these click on <kbd>X</kbd> to scale horizontally and <kbd>Y</kbd> to scale vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Stencil Widget addon](https://github.com/artistCDMJ/stencil_widget/raw/master/download/stencil_widget.zip) by Kgeogeo that gives you a really good way to control brush texture and brush mask texture set as Stencil. I use this almost all the time when manipulating image textures as well as even using it to adjust procedural textures set to stencil.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Although I am wondering if you would happen to know how to reset the size and aspect ratio.